# constant pressure effects on temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

Is constant pressure applied to a substance (fluid or gas) adding in a significant way to its temperature? If not why? Shouldn't the increased density of the molecules cause them to vibrate more i.e. higher temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is constant pressure applied to a substance (fluid or gas) adding in a significant way to its temperature?

It does.  Take a look at [Gay Lussac's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay%E2%80%93Lussac_law#Pressure-temperature_law)

It states that $P \propto T$ for constant $V$ and $n$.